# PDOException error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, symfony1

I occasionally (not always) caught error as follows , not sure for the exact condition for this failure.

Error (in app_prod.log and apache error log) :

> [Thu Dec 11 13:29:16 2014] [error] [client 126.186.1xx.1xx]
>   PDOException was thrown when trying to manipulate session data.
>   Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry 'jcifosn5dncrlthpaje2g1gim6' for key 'PRIMARY'

I use session table using MySQL.

It seems the sessionRead() in sfPDOSessionStorage failed and I assume the error was caused because the fetchAll() returns no value but it actually exists.

- related topic: http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=15766
- past trac number related to this issue: #4777

The comment in the tract #4777 said "// we anyway expect either no rows, or one row with one column. fetchColumn, seems to be buggy #4777" , however not mention to what the bug itself is.

Is this symfony issue or PDO issue?

Does anyone has any idea?

Your support highly appreciated.
Thanks!!

[version]
- symfony 1.4.20
- php 5.4.29
- MySQL 5.6.19